# Unity aim down sights with multiple scopes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make an Aim Down Sight script where the gun moves to the center of the camera. Currently, I'm using Vector3.Lerp to lerp between a “normal Vector” and an “aiming Vector” which I set up via the editor. Now I have the problem that I have many attachments for multiple guns in my game so the “point” which has to be in the center of the screen changes with each scope attached to the gun and I really don't want to set up a new vector3 for each variation of guns and scopes. I tried many things like calculating the distance between the screen center and the middle of the scope and then creating a new vector3 off this distance via script but nothing worked as expected. Do you guys have any ideas or suggestions how to get this working?

I'm really thankfully for every reply!

Comment: tbh the scope should be at the center in any case , no ? It would be weird not to have it at the center.. Maybe post an image or smtg

Comment: @Ced the height can vary, and it usually does

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do it is to have array of positions for the camera and keep track of scope you have currently on.

```
public Vector3[] scopePositions;
public int scopeID;
```

Later, when you change the scope, just change the `scopeID` and when aiming down the sights, use it like this:

```
Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(normalPosition, scopePositions[scopeID], time);
```

**Solution 2**
You could set up your scope structure like this:

Scope model > Empty game object with some dummy script.
When you have it like that, you can easily set the position in code:

```
scopePosition = GetComponentInChildren<DummyComponent>().transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
```

or something like that.

Comment: Should work perfectly fine but then I'd have to set 100+ vectors for all the gun and scope combinations :/

Comment: I added another solution.

Comment: Hmm.. seems like I'm doing sth. wrong because it isn't working as expected at all. I'll keep searching for another way. Thank you so much for your answer anyways!

Comment: I'm just wondering how games like cod battlefield or any other shooter is doing this...

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if you still want to find how to do it but in my case :

- I have a gun parented to a AimPosition gameobject
- The gun got a socket for the scope
- The scope got a socket called (aimCenter) that is basically the center of the scope lens

With these three info i can set the local position of my AimPostion at :

```
x = 0(center x axis)
y = - (scopeSocket.localPosition.y + aimCenter.transform.localPosition.y)
z = whatever you want (me 0,58)
```

so basically i am modifing the parent of my weapon with :

the height between the gun (central position of weapon) and the scope
and the height between the scope socket and my aimDesired position wich is the middle of your lens.

I know that this setup is extremely precise but i hope it can help someone.

[there you have it, just without the gunAimPosition parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xPdX.png)